# US domestic flights: cutoff time

Tags: usa, air-travel, regulations

Is there a governing authority that has issued a rule that aircraft doors are closed (no more passengers may board) 10 minutes before the planned departure time?

Comment: @downvoters: if taking the time to downvote, please either make a constructive comment.  Better: edit and sharpen the question.

Answer (score 8):

There is no government regulation of this nature. Airlines set their own policies. For instance, [United says](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/travel/airport/process/default.aspx):

> For flights within the U.S., all customers must be on board the
>   aircraft 15 minutes before the scheduled departure time. We recommend
>   being at the boarding gate at least 15 minutes before departure to
>   ensure that you’re on the aircraft before the doors are closed.

If you arrive at the gate after the cut-off time, you may find your seat has already been given to a standby passenger or that it is simply too late to board. They may also be able to accommodate you anyway. But it's a matter of airline policy, not law.

Comment: And note that this is stated in the United Contract of Carriage, which dictates the conditions that you agreed to in conjunction with purchasing your ticket. It's not just something listed on their website.